# Microsoft Edge requesting new page on back/forward button

Tags: microsoft-edge, back

The latest version of the Microsoft Edge browser (41.162...) requests a new page when the back and forward buttons are clicked. I've tested multiple browsers on multiple platforms and only Edge exhibits this behavior.

Here's a **[test page](http://www.easynotecards.com/state1)** that displays the timestamp the page was created. Click the "Next Page" link and then use the back and forward buttons. Notice that the timestamp is different each time for Edge but not other browsers.

The previous version of Edge did not request a new page each time.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think StackOverflow is the best place to post this as there won't be an easy workaround for this beside circumventing most of the browser internals via your own UI & cacheing and that can be broken by the user clicking the back button that they're accustomed to. I recommend filing a bug on Edge here: http://bugs.microsoftedge.com to find out if it's by design or not and potentially get it fixed. Additionally, please make sure to state why this is impactful to your site and more importantly to your end users.

One reason I can see fetching the URL again is that the content will be fresh because not every user wants to go back to "stale" content they just want to go back to that page, for example - and doing a new navigate ensures a clean slate.

Comment: Appreciate the reply. [I submitted as a bug](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/platform/issues/15508003/). FYI, I use for back/forward button detection. I store the page id (based on the timestamp) in a hidden field in order to determine if the page was reached via back/forward button. Since the content is always new w/ Edge there's no way to know if the back/forward button was used.