# Remember form data on back button with Microsoft Edge

Tags: microsoft-edge

I created a web application using ASP.NET MVC (not core) containing search and result pages.

From the result page whenever I go back using the back button on other browsers such as Chrome and Firefox, it remembers the text and dropdown value information.

But on Microsoft Edge it clears all my text box and dropdown to its default. Is this a browser issue or a bug? Is there something that we can do thru code?

I've found something similar but it doesn't address this exact behavior.
[Related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48198771/microsoft-edge-requesting-new-page-on-back-forward-button)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have reproduced the problem in the Legacy version of Microsoft Edge (Microsoft Edge 44.18362.449.0), but in the [New Microsoft Edge](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/edge/?form=MA13DE&OCID=MA13DE) (chromium based) it works well. It can be possible that it is the default behavior in the Legacy version of the Edge. You could feedback this issue in [Microsoft Edge Legacy Forum](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/edge/forum?sort=LastReplyDate&dir=Desc&tab=All&status=all&mod=&modAge=&advFil=&postedAfter=&postedBefore=&threadType=All&isFilterExpanded=false&page=1) or install the New Microsoft Edge and use it.

As a workaround, you could try to use WebStorage to store the form data, when page reload, check whether the storage contains the value, then set the value. Please check the following sample:

JavaScript code:

```
<script>
    window.onload = function () {
        if (sessionStorage.name && sessionStorage.password) {
            document.getElementById("name").value = sessionStorage.name;
            document.getElementById("password").value = sessionStorage.password;
        }
    };

    function storedata() {
        if (typeof (Storage) !== "undefined") {
            var name = document.getElementById("name").value;
            var password = document.getElementById("password").value;

            sessionStorage.name = name;
            sessionStorage.password = password;

            document.getElementById("res").innerHTML = "Your datas restored";
        } else {
            document.getElementById("res").innerHTML = "Sorry, your browser does not support web storage...";
        }
    } 
</script>
```

web page:

```
<form id="form1" runat="server" autocomplete="on">
    <div>
        UserID: <asp:TextBox ID="name" runat="server"></asp:TextBox><br />
        Password: <asp:TextBox ID="password" runat="server"></asp:TextBox><br />
       Remember Me: <asp:CheckBox ID="selectall" runat="server" />  <br />
        <asp:Button ID="btn_signIn" runat="server" Text="Button" OnClick="btn_signIn_Click" OnClientClick="storedata();" /><br />
        <asp:Label ID="lblresult" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>
        <span id="res"></span>
    </div>
</form>
```

More detail information about using WebStorage, please check the following links:

[Web Storage API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Storage_API)

[HTML5 Web Storage](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp)

Comment: thank you yes it looks like it is a recurring issue but it works on the new Microsoft Edge. Thank you for your answer.